# Modifying/Overriding WP_Query Before Wordpress Inits

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In Woo Commerce I would like to be able to dynamically change what products are appearing on certain product category pages, without having to manually change product categories in the back end.

I have achieved 'overriding' the 'loop' using the following code just before the loop...

```
// Using array of products I pulled from DB
foreach($_products as $featured_product) {
    $post_object = get_post($featured_product->get_id());
    setup_postdata($GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object);
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'grid-product' );
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

This solution does half the job, it makes the product appear on the template the way I want.

However all the schema code is missing and there are some other things popping up in the template because it doesn't 'see' and products in the main page query.

Some research later and I found this hook which seemed like it would solve my issues.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', function($q) {
    $ids = [10, 20, 30];
    $q->set('post__in', $ids);
});
```

This is for a Woo Commerce archive page, so I want this code to pull in the products with those IDs I passed.

Nothing is shown in the loop and I did try updating the post_count property in the WP_Query to try get the loop to fire as well.

Can anyone offer any more suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `pre_get_post` and override query parameters using `is_tax` to implement conditional check.

Comment: woocommerce_product_query is a woo commerce friendly version of pre_get_posts

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I am aware of `woocommerce_product_query` and have found issues in implementing it properly at times and hence I suggested `pre_get_post` to be used directly. Still `$q->is_tax('<TAXONOMY_SLUG_HERE>') should work if `woocommerce_product_query` is working fine for you.

Comment: Right, but I am not asking how to check for a taxonomy, I already have an array of product IDs that I want to show on the archive page, my problem is they are not showing. I've got that code snippet as is on my testing env, so it should be effecting every single page query. I'll add the tax check in when I solve this issue if that makes sense.